# How do a custom method applicable to various models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method called capitalizeEachWord. Inside this method there is an attribute called company

```
class BusCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company
  before_save :capitalizeEachWord
  validates :company,presence: true,
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                    format: /^([a-zA-z0-9]+\s?){1,}$/

  def capitalizeEachWord
    self.company=self.company.downcase.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  end
end
```

I would like that this method not use the attribute company directly, but receives this attribute as a parameter for doesn't do it dependent of the model BusCompany. Something as the following. The problem is that this method I going to use in various models and don't want to write it in each model but use the inheritance

```
class BusCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company
  before_save :capitalizeEachWord(self.company)
  validates :company,presence: true,
                       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                       format: /^([a-zA-z0-9]+\s?){1,}$/

  def capitalizeEachWord(attribute)
    self.attribute=self.attribute.downcase.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: nicooga if the user wrote "FERNANDO DANIEL " I have to use strip for eliminate spaces at the end of string in blank and then titleize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code into `config/initializers/capitalizer.rb`

```
module Capitalizer
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def capitalize(*attributes)
      @attributes_to_capitalize = attributes
      before_save :capitalize_each_word
    end

    def attributes_to_capitalize
      Array.new(@attributes_to_capitalize)
    end
  end

  def capitalize_each_word
    self.class.attributes_to_capitalize.each do |attr|
      if value = send(attr)
        self.send("#{attr}=", value.strip.titleize)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then in your class:

```
class BusCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Capitalizer
  capitalize :company

  ...
end
```

Comment: spickermann if the user wrote "FERNANDO DANIEL       "    I have to use  strip for eliminate spaces at the end of string in blank and then titleize

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend you override the setter for company instead of using error prone callbacks, like this:

```
class BusCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  # you can also use #titleize instead of capitalize each word
  # also use try, in case `arg` is nil
  def company=(arg)
    super arg.try(:titleize)
  end
end
```

Then you can use modules to wrap this functionality into a reusable unit. Throw this in a file in your concerns folder, or just in to the models folder:

```
module CapitalizedSetter
  def capitalize_setter(*attr_names)
    # for each attr name, redifine the setter so it supers the titleized argument instead
    attr_names.each do |attr|
      define_method(:"#{attr}=") { |arg| super arg.try(:titleize) }
    end
  end
end
```

Finally extend it into the desired models:

```
class BusCompany
  extend CapitalizedSetter

  capitalized_setter :company
end
```